# Is there Python formatting for below code?

Tags: python, arraylist, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I am using Jupyter notebook Python 3 with using pandas-datareader to fetch the data from Yahoo Finance.
If I use the below code for a single security it looks (output) perfect matrix

```
aapl = pdr.data.get_data_yahoo('aapl', start='2020-03-10' , end='2020-03-18')
aapl
```

But if I use it for multiple securities, it does not seem too give a property matrix as output.

```
all_data = {}
for ticker in ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']:
    all_data[ticker] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker)
all_data
```

I am expecting output to be the same as the first code

Comment: If I run both pieces of your code and specify the same `start` and `end` criteria, then `aapl == all_data['AAPL']` is all True and when printed, they appear identical. If you're seeing something different, you need to be specific about what it is that you're getting.

Comment: thank you so much David, your reply very useful for me.